# Protractor:count() doesn't work outside of expect()

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I tried to write a function to wait for the number of some kinds of elements to be a specific number, my code is:

```
waitelementnum= function (num) {
    var elmnum=element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']")).count();
    browser.wait(function () {
        return (elmnum>num);
    }, 10000);
};
```

but it always timeout. then I try to print the result of count like:

```
console.log(element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']")).count());
```

nothing was printed out;

but when I tried:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']")).count()).toEqual(2);
```

it reported:

```
expecting 1 to be 2.
```

So world anybody kindly tell me what's wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `count()` as a lot of other methods in `protractor` **returns a promise**. `expect()` is intentionally enhanced by `jasminewd` to resolve promises implicitly.

If you want to see the actual `count()` value, you can resolve the promise excplitly with `.then()`:

```
var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

See also: [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow).